# Recursively count the occurences of 8 as a digit in a given number

Tags: recursion, count, numbers, digits

Given a non-negative int n, compute recursively (no loops) the count of the occurrences of 8 as a digit, except that an 8 with another 8 immediately to its left counts double, so 8818 yields 4. Note that mod (%) by 10 yields the rightmost digit (126 % 10 is 6), while divide (/) by 10 removes the rightmost digit (126 / 10 is 12).

I attempted it and my code is below. Please also let me know what am I doing wrong in the code. Many Thanks in Advance!! Ignore main().

count8(8) → 1

count8(818) → 2

count8(8818) → 4

```java
public int count8(int n) {
  
  int cd=0,pd=0,c=0;  // cd for current digit, pd for previous digit,c=count
  
  if(n==0)           // base condition
    return 0;
  
  cd = n%10;       // finding the rightmost digit
  
  if(cd==8)// if rightmost digit id 8 then
  {
    c++;
  
    n=n/10;// moving towards left from rightmost digit
  
    if(n!=0)
      pd=n%10;//second rightmost digit(similarly as secondlast digit)
  
    if(cd==8 && pd==8)// if rightmost and second rightmost equals 8, double c
      c=c*2;
  }     
  else         // if cd not equals 8 then
    c=0;
  
  return c + count8(n/10);//adding count and recursively calling method  
}
```

```
            Expected    Run     
count8(8) → 1             1 OK  
count8(818) → 2           2 OK  
count8(8818) → 4          3 X   
count8(8088) → 4          3 X   
count8(123) → 0           0 OK  
count8(81238) → 2         2 OK  
count8(88788) → 6         4 X   
count8(8234) → 1          1 OK  
count8(2348) → 1          1 OK  
count8(23884) → 3         2 X   
count8(0) → 0             0 OK  
count8(1818188) → 5       4 X   
count8(8818181) → 5       4 X   
count8(1080) → 1          1 OK  
count8(188) → 3           2 X   
count8(88888) → 9         5 X   
count8(9898) → 2          2 OK  
count8(78) → 1            1 OK
```

Comment: So what _is_ wrong with your code?  Provide actual and expected outputs. Also, consider comments in your code and format it before posting.

Comment: Hi Henk, Thanks for your time. I did as you told.

Comment: You have one simple logic error. Since this looks like homework I'm not gong to point it out directly. Use a debugger (very easy to learn) or insert some tracing with Console.WriteLine(). Go through your code step by step and compare actual and intended values.

Comment: Side note: you also have quite a few superfluous statements, like:  `else c = 0;` , `if(cd==8 &&`. When you simplify the code becomes easier to read.

Comment: As a bit of a clue, look specifically into what happens when you have double `8`s.

Comment: I got it . c=c + 2*c; will be right. But One case is still not right. count8(88888)->  9 is expected result. But Mine is coming 7. Except this case , all other cases are right.Can you enlighten me on this?

Comment: Not without seeing your new code. (But don't remove the original posted code). But the same rules would apply: walk through it by yourself. Simply printing `n` to the console at the top of the method would let you trace the recursion.

Comment: First of all, *please* go back and read the introductory tour.  Among other things, you missed the important links to [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If nothing else, the top of each logic block -- especially a function -- should have a **print** statement to report all of the input parameters.  In this case, 2-4 more to trace logic and data flow should have solved your problem a full day ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simplify it a little more

```
public int count8(int number, bool prevWas8 = false) 
{
    int num8s = 0;

    if( number == 0) //base case
        return 0;

    if( number%10 == 8) //we found an 8!
        num8s++;

    if (prevWas8 && num8s > 0) // we found two 8's in a row!
        num8s++;

    return num8s + count8(number/10, num8s>0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bwall. One of the most simplified code I have ever seen. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int count8(int n)
{
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    if(n % 10 == 8)
    {
        if(n / 10 % 10 == 8)
            return 2+count8(n/10);
        return 1+count8(n/10);
    }
    return count8(n/10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int count8(int n) {
  int c=0;
  if (n==0){
    return 0;

  }
  else{
    if (n%10==8 && (n/10)%10==8){
      c+=2;
    }
    else if (n%10==8 && (n/10)%10!=8){
      c++;
    }
  }
  return c+count8(n/10);
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. Code dumps aren't generally very useful.

Answer (score -1):

If you want simple:

```
public int count8(int n) {

    return (n < 8) ? 0 : ((n % 10 == 8) ? ((n % 100 == 88) ? 2 : 1) : 0) + count8(n / 10);
}
```